# How to flip/reorganize the data retrieved from an SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Right now, I have an SQL query that returns data in the following way:
[image: What I have]

There are repeating values in both the "SCHOOL" and the "TEACHER" columns, e.g. School A and School C both have teachers named Ms. Smith.

I need to present my data in this way instead:

[image: What I want]

Is it possible to do something like this directly in the SQL select statement (with or without the dynamic column names, if that's impossible)? What are the differences in how I would go about each approach? Could I get some examples, please?

My original select statement is very complex and I don't want to post it since this problem then wouldn't be relatable to anyone else. So I am asking in general, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: What relational database (and what version of that database) are you using?  Different databases will have different syntax and different versions will have different options.

Comment: I am using `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you could use the PIVOT operator. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    School,
    [Ms. Smith],
    [Mr. Rogers],
    [Mr. Berkenheim],
    [Ms. Roberts],
    [Mr. Ashby],
    [Ms. Robinson]
FROM <data_table> AS D
PIVOT (
    SUM(NumberOfStudents) FOR Teacher IN ([Ms. Smith],[Mr. Rogers],[Mr. Berkenheim],[Ms. Roberts],[Mr. Ashby],[Ms. Robinson])
) P
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select School, 
sum(case Teacher = 'Ms. Smith' then [# Students] else 0 end) as [Ms. Smith],
sum(case Teacher = 'Mr. Rogers' then [# Students] else 0 end) as [Mr. Rogers],
sum(case Teacher = 'Mr. Berkenheim' then [# Students] else 0 end) as [Mr. Berkenheim],
sum(case Teacher = 'Ms. Roberts' then [# Students] else 0 end) as [Ms. Roberts]
group by School
```