# Reorganizing Key/Value data using Select Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have some tables that are effectively organized as in this example:

[image: Basic Schema]

Broadly speaking, there are a number of "assets" that possess a many-to-many list of key/value pairs in the form of "tags" with names and values.  Each asset can have any subset of tags, and each tag for each asset has a value.

If one were to simply dump the data showing the assets, tag names, and tag values, you might end up with results such as this:

[image: Data, but not how I'd like it]

However, the way I would actually like to organize the data is like this:

[image: Now that looks better]

**Is it possible, using this schema, to instead be able to select data in this method?**  Effectively, this involves turning each entry in the tag table and turning it into a column, and then filling in each of these columns with the value associated with that tag for each asset, where applicable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17956281/1961815) has the exact same problem, however it is not acceptable for me for the following reasons:

1. It is regarding Oracle, while I am using **PostgreSQL**
2. All of the given answers resort to hard-coded queries citing specific data names, whereas I require mine to **work dynamically for any data**.
3. It simply doesn't have enough views.  Viewed 37 times?  I don't believe any real experts ever saw that.

Additionally, **is there a name for this sort of data selection**?  I believe that it is an abstract and universal problem, but I do not know what it would be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern of design is sometimes called Entity Attribute Value (EAV). You can create the query you want dynamically, although it's a bit of effort. I'm not sure there's a way to return an anonymous table type, so I had to create a function to create a function:

```
Create or replace function generatecrosstab() returns void as $BODY$
Declare
    sql varchar := '';
    type varchar := '(assetid int, ';
    sep varchar := '';
    tagid int;
    tname varchar(50);
Begin
    for tagid, tname in select id, tagname from tag order by id
    loop
        sql := sql || sep || 'max(case tagid when ' 
            || tagid::varchar || ' then tagvalue end) ' || tname;
        type := type || sep || tname || ' varchar(255)';
        sep := ', ';
    end loop;
    type := type || ')';
    sql = 'create or replace function crosstab() returns table ' 
       || type || ' as $$' 
       || ' select assetid, ' || sql
       || ' from assettag group by assetid order by assetid;'
       || ' $$ Language sql;';
    execute sql;
End;
$BODY$ Language plpgsql;
```

If you execute this function with, for example:

```
select generatecrosstab();
```

It will create a function crosstab() which you can select from:

```
Select * From crosstab();
```

The [tablefunc module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) has some functions that might simplify things.

**<kbd>[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/41901/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Do you know what versions of postgreSQL this works in?  Is there a minimum version necessary?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're as well placed to figure that out as I am